Traefik 3 returns "404 page not found" on mailpit 8025 port - cannot reverse proxy to specific container port
The problem is rather general but I have an example with mailpit: I cannot reverse proxy to a docker container app which uses a specific port.
I'm using Traefik and I set up these files:
Traefik/docker-compose.yaml:
services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./htpasswd:/htpasswd
      - ./traefik.yaml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yaml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`localhost`) && (PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`))"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.middlewares=auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.usersfile=/htpasswd"
    networks:
      - traefik

  whoami:
    image: traefik/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/whoami`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls=true"
    networks:
      - traefik

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true

Having this static configuration
Traefik/traefik.yaml:
api:
  dashboard: true

entrypoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"

log:
  level: TRACE

metrics:
  addInternals: true

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"


This works and I can run
$ curl -sk https://localhost/whoami | head 
Hostname: ea1b0e62d773
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: ::1
IP: 172.19.0.3
RemoteAddr: 172.19.0.2:37404
GET /whoami HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: curl/8.9.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip

I can also access the Traefik dashboard at https://localhost/dashboard/.
However, if I add another service like e.g. mailpit:
Mailpit/docker-compose.yml:
services:
  mailpit:
    image: axllent/mailpit
    container_name: mailpit
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - mailpit-data:/data
    ports:
      - 8025:8025
      - 1025:1025
    environment:
      MP_MAX_MESSAGES: 5000
      MP_DATABASE: /data/mailpit.db
      MP_SMTP_AUTH_ACCEPT_ANY: 1
      MP_SMTP_AUTH_ALLOW_INSECURE: 1
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/mailpit`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.service=mailpit"
      - "traefik.http.services.mailpit.loadbalancer.server.port=8025"
    networks:
      - traefik

volumes:
  mailpit-data:

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true

Calling the interface via traefik results in 404 page not found.
$ curl -sk https://localhost/mailpit | head
404 page not found

Yet, the service is up and running and I can access mailpit dashboard right at http://localhost:8025, but not via traefik.
But the traefik dashboard lists the mailpit service correctly at url: http://172.19.0.4:8025 and accessing it within the traefik server itself works fine.
$ docker exec -it traefik wget -O - http://172.19.0.4:8025 | head
Connecting to 172.19.0.4:8025 (172.19.0.4:8025)
writing to stdout
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">

<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive">

Yet, this output is not reported back.
What is wrong?
(Rewrote section, since Stack Overflow thinks this is spam)

Mailpit gets up and serves at 1025 and 8025. Mailpit dashboard is served at http 8025. Works fine at http://localhost:8025.
Traefik reports router and service correctly to http://172.19.0.4:8025.
I can connect to http://172.19.0.4:8025 from within the traefik container successfully.
Somehow https://localhost/mailpit does not make this connection.

I played around with different setting to no avail.
** Edit **
Traefik seems to forward the path to the service as-is as pointed by @larsks here. Stripping the path could help, but this causes another series of problems.
Therefore, the only easy solution is, adjusting the Host of the Traefik labels without any Path matchers, like this
services:
  mailpit:
    image: axllent/mailpit
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - mailpit-data:/data
    ports:
      - 8025:8025
      - 1025:1025
    environment:
      MP_MAX_MESSAGES: 5000
      MP_DATABASE: /data/mailpit.db
      MP_SMTP_AUTH_ACCEPT_ANY: 1
      MP_SMTP_AUTH_ALLOW_INSECURE: 1
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.rule=Host(`mailpit.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.service=mailpit"
      - "traefik.http.services.mailpit.loadbalancer.server.port=8025"
    networks:
      - traefik

volumes:
  mailpit-data:

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true

Having a dedicated host ("mailpit.localhost") for the service.

fwiw, I was unable to reproduce this problem. You can see my complete test setup here; after bringing up both compose files, I can successfully reach https://localhost/mailpit (and https://localhost/whoami).

I would be interested in seeing the actual dump of your router configuration from https://localhost/api/http/routers

The localhost/api/routers output is too long for a comment here at Stack Overflow. To me it looks ok. Any idea how to pass this output in here? Or what should I check?

"This is talking directly to the Mailpit service and not via Traefik" That is not correct. If you look at the traefik container, 8443 is where the websecure endpoint is exposed.

When people ask for additional information, edit your question to include the new material. That allows it to be formatted in a useful fashion, and also makes it easier to find (people might not notice it in the comments).

"This is talking directly to the Mailpit service and not via Traefik", yes I noticed and dropped that comment. I was wrong.

@larsks I played around with your samples. Traefik always picks the very first port the container creates. And I guess, this is why your setting works: you are using whoami which opens only 1 single port. You may drop the "traefik.http.services.whoami.loadbalancer.server.port=..." line completely, instruct whoami to open up another port and it will still work.
However, mailpit is offering the admin panel on 8025, which is the 2nd port of this container after 1025. Try using the real mailpit instead of whoami in your example.

That has nothing to do with the problem. Traefik uses whichever port you set in ...loadbalancer.server.port, regardless of whether it is "first" or not.

@larsks Ok, I cloned your repo here, and just exchanged the "whomi" image of the real mailpit service, and it stopped working.
$ curl -k https://localhost:8443/mailpit
44 page not found


See my answer for the actual problem. Traefik (and the example!) are all working correctly; the problem is with mailpit.

Traefik is working as expected. The 404 error is actually coming from the mailpit container.  You have configured traefik like this:
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/mailpit`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.service=mailpit"
      - "traefik.http.services.mailpit.loadbalancer.server.port=8025"

This means when you make a request to https://localhost/mailpit, traefik forwards this request to http://mailpit:8025/mailpit. Note that the URL preserves the original request path. If you attempt to access this directly...
$ curl http://localhost:8025/mailpit
404 page not found

...you will get the same error. Mailpit doesn't know it's sitting behind a prefix, but fortunately it has a --webroot option for exactly this situation. You need to include that in your configuration:
services:
  mailpit:
    image: docker.io/axllent/mailpit
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - mailpit-data:/data
    ports:
      - 8025:8025
      - 1025:1025
    environment:
      MP_MAX_MESSAGES: 5000
      MP_DATABASE: /data/mailpit.db
      MP_SMTP_AUTH_ACCEPT_ANY: 1
      MP_SMTP_AUTH_ALLOW_INSECURE: 1
    command:
      - --webroot=mailpit
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/mailpit`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.service=mailpit"
      - "traefik.http.services.mailpit.loadbalancer.server.port=8025"
    networks:
      - traefik

volumes:
  mailpit-data:

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true

This would solve the problem, except for one last thing: the mailpit image includes a healthcheck that periodically runs /mailpit --readyz, and it looks like that command will never return successfully when using the --webroot option on the service (because the healthcheck doesn't know about the --webroot configuration). We need to build a custom image to resolve that problem. That's pretty simple; we create a local Dockerfile like this:
FROM docker.io/axllent/mailpit

HEALTHCHECK --interval=10s CMD ["/mailpit", "--webroot", "mailpit", "readyz"]

And modify compose.yaml to build the image for us:
services:
  mailpit:
    build:
      context: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - mailpit-data:/data
    ports:
      - 8025:8025
      - 1025:1025
    environment:
      MP_MAX_MESSAGES: 5000
      MP_DATABASE: /data/mailpit.db
      MP_SMTP_AUTH_ACCEPT_ANY: 1
      MP_SMTP_AUTH_ALLOW_INSECURE: 1
    command:
      - --webroot=mailpit
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/mailpit`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.service=mailpit"
      - "traefik.http.services.mailpit.loadbalancer.server.port=8025"
    networks:
      - traefik

volumes:
  mailpit-data:

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true

With these two changes, access to https://localhost/mailpit resolves to the mailpit web ui. Note that this will only work after the container status is "healthy"; traefik will not direct traefik to unhealthy services.

I have updated the example repository with all of these changes.

Ah, this sounds reasonable! I thought the rule "Host(localhost) && PathPrefix(/mailpit)" is only for the Traefik router to find the proper service, but not to include this in the request on forwarding. At least I do not recall this behavior from caddy2. Would it not be preferrable to strip the '/mailpit' part at the Traefik side (http://localhost:8443/mailpit/BLAH) and forward as http://mailpit:8025/BLAH internally?
Since if not, I have to find a fix for any service by adjusting the webroot portion. This seems not right.

You can configure traefik to strip the /mailpit part (see the stripprefix middleware), but that leads to another problem: if the backend service (mailpit) doesn't know it's sitting behind a prefix, it will generate requests for things like /app/somefile.css; when your browser requests this, the request won't get routed to the backend because it doesn't match the prefix.

Thx, but this is too much of a hazzle to deal with each and every service. I reverted the traefik rule and dropped the Path Prefix match in favor of a extended Host. This works like charm.

If you think this answer helped you understand the problem and reach a solution, please mark it as "accepted". Thanks!

It is worth noting that the healthcheck works perfectly fine provided you set the webroot via an Docker environment variable instead of a flag, so MP_WEBROOT: mailpit instead of the command:... --webroot=mailpit.


Are you sure about the Mailpit has necessary configuration to support SSL traffic? I think if you try this it might work as charm.
$ curl -sk http://localhost/mailpit 

If my solution [1] doesn't help, you might try modifying the 'Mailpit/docker-compose.yml' file:
DELETE this line: - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.tls=true" 
ADD this line: - "traefik.http.routers.mailpit.entrypoints=websecure" 


I hope your problem will be solved.

Thx!
Traefik should terminate the SSL connection and forward the pure HTTP request and not the HTTPS. I think this is the core business of traefik as a reverse proxy.
However, I tried what you suggested and neither curl http://localhost/mailpit/ nor curl -sk https://localhost/mailpit/ work.
